# Syntax error while using $setOnInsert in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am working on mongodb/pymongo/python and have written the following snippet of code:

```
db_table.collection_table.findAndModify(
    {
        query: { _id: '1' }, 
        update: {
            $setOnInsert: {'_id': '1',
                'tablename': 'Buyer',
                'collectionname':'Buyer_Report', 
                'viewlink':'All_Buyers', 
                'new_table': 'yes' }
        },
        new: true,
        upsert: true,
})
```

The above code is generating syntax error : invalid syntax  in $setOnInsert part. What can be possible cause of error?

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Comment: Could it be that `$setOnInsert` is supposed to be a string? Maybe try `'$setOnInsert'`

Comment: BTW, it is not valid syntax for Pymongo. You are mixing shell command syntax with Pymongo syntax. [http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify)

Answer (score 0):

Is that supposed to be `python` code?

Surely it should look more like this:

```
db_table.collection_table.findAndModify({
    'query': { _id: '1' },
    'update': {
        '$setOnInsert': {
            '_id': '1','tablename': 'Buyer', 'collectionname':'Buyer_Report', 'viewlink':'All_Buyers', 'new_table': 'yes'
            }
        },
    'new': True,
    'upsert': True,
})
```

From the `pymongo` manual it appears that the type of `upsert` & `new` is `Boolean`. So the values should be `True` rather than `'true'`.

Comment: @max_hellrocker, if that answer was useful for you, please consider clicking the tick next to it to accept it.

Comment: or, alternatively, add this to the top:

`query, update, new, upsert, _id = 'query', 'update', 'new', 'upsert', '_id'`

then you only need to add quotes to `$setOnInsert`